# Why does the x & y values not increment?

Tags: javascript, joystick

I am building a virtual joystick and this is part of the code that I made so that when the joystick is in between a certain value the x and y value will keep on incrementing by a certain value for instance when the joystick is between 1 and 20 for deltaX it will keep incrementing every second once or if it is in between 21 and 40 it will increment twice every second and I want it to keep incrementing and not staying at the same value of two. When I try this code, the x & y values just stick to 1, 2 or 3 and doesn't increment, could anyone suggest why this happens?

edit:
The If statements need to be outside the function as the joystick breaks and doesn't run if its inside.

```
       if (joystick.deltaX() >= 1 && joystick.deltaX() <= 20) {
            (function movex1() {
                x = x + 1;
                setTimeout(movex1, 1000);
            })();
        }

        if (joystick.deltaX() >= 21 && joystick.deltaX() <= 40) {
            (function movex2() {
                x = x + 2;
                setTimeout(movex2, 1000);
            })();
        }

        if (joystick.deltaX() >= 41 && joystick.deltaX() <= 60) {
            (function movex3() {
                x = x + 3;
                setTimeout(movex3, 1000);
            })();
        }

        if (joystick.deltaY() >= 1 && joystick.deltaY() <= 20) {
            (function movey1() {
                y = y + 1;
                setTimeout(movey1, 1000);
            })();
        }

        if (joystick.deltaY() >= 21 && joystick.deltaY() <= 40) {
            (function movey2() {
                y = y + 2;
                setTimeout(movey2, 1000);
            })();
        }

        if (joystick.deltaY() >= 41 && joystick.deltaY() <= 60) {
            (function movey3() {
                y = y + 3;
                setTimeout(movey3, 1000);
            })();
        }
```

Comment: [Don't repeat yourself!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: When are all these if statements triggered/executed?

Comment: warning: once triggered, they'll never stop

Comment: @moffeltje they are executed when I move the joystick to the left i.e in deltaX and deltaY. The if statements execute but will only read the value of the added number to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your code executes, joystick.deltaX() and joystick.deltaY() more likely have a value of 0, so no timeout is ever set.

Also, avoid so many ifs when you can just replace them with a division.

Why not use an interval?

```
var x = 0, y = 0;

// Execute every second
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    x += Math.ceil(joystick.deltaX() / 20);
    y += Math.ceil(joystick.deltaY() / 20);
}, 1000);

// Stop after 20 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}, 20000)
```

Comment: Thanks this works much better that my code, only problem is it doesn't do it every second it is pretty much instantaneous so that it goes to a 1000 in about 2 seconds.

Comment: You most likely are executing this piece of code everytime the joystick moves (which sets a timer everytime it moves)